# IE11 CSS opacity transition for table rows not working

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11

http://jsbin.com/qusewehobi

In the example above, clicking the button adds and removes the *selectedRow* class of a div and two table rows. The opacity should change from 1.0 to 0.25 smoothly due to a transition declaration on the common class of those elements.

This works in Chrome 43.0.2357.130 (64-bit), but not in IE 11.0.9600 - only the DIV element changes. Remove the transition declaration and the opacity changes reliably.

Am I missing some subtlety of CSS or is this a bug?

Comment: Taking the answer as confirmation and submitted as a bug: https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedbackdetail/view/1543745/ie11-css-opacity-transition-for-table-rows-not-working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't tell you why it doesn't work properly in IE, but I'm not impressed at all. What I noticed is that those that don't work in IE are the `TR`s with the class `.toggleTarget`, so if you add the text within divs it will work properly.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
   <head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  </head>

   <body>
     <div class="toggleTarget">DIV CONTENT</div>
     <table>
       <tr>
         <td>
           <div class="toggleTarget">TABLE ROW 0</div>
          </td>
       </tr>
       <tr><td>
         <div class="toggleTarget">TABLE ROW 1</div>
           </td></tr>
     </table>
     <button onclick="$('.toggleTarget').toggleClass('selectedRow');">Click Me</button>
   </body>
</html>
```